# Where is the goal metric from Google Analytics 4 in SSIS?

Tags: google-analytics, ssis, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I can't seem to find the Goal Conversions Metric in SSIS with the new GA Property Type (GA4 - Web+Apps).

I used to use the GA3 (UA - Universal Analytics) before, but now all my data has to be extracted by the new property (GA4)

Where can I find the goalCompletionAll and other goals from the new website?

Is there something else I should be doing in the website before extracting the data in SSIS?

Comment: In GA4 there is no goal concept. You need to set up the event tracking and specify what event is conversion event. Then the conversion event count should be similar with your goal complete in UA. But the number is expected higher.

Comment: I see, thank you for giving me this information.
I will try do something about it based on what you told me.